# Inject variable file at run/build time using webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

*Edited to be more brief:*

I would like to be able to use styles, images in variables in my React app based upon the NPM command - eg:

`npm run start:firstConfig`

And:

`npm run start:secondConfig`

The `Webpack.DefinePlugin` does this for a single variable - I am able to use the npm command to pass a variable to Webpack, but I'm looking for a robust way to do this with assets and variables.

Comment: What's wrong with the `webpack.DefinePlugin` ?

Comment: You're doing the `require('./app/variableFiles/${varsFile}/config.js');` within your node app right?

Comment: The require is in my Webpack file - I am aware that I can't use a variable inside my app with an `import` statement, which would be a really easy fixe for this... lol.

Comment: You can.  The config is just a node app

Comment: Sorry - I mean I can't use a variable in an `import` statement in my React code. I *think* the problem is that global/local vars work different in node and React, and Webpack is the middleman, which I'm finding a little confusing.